# Why does tf.layers.dense throw AttributeError?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to understand what `tf.layers.dense` does to an array and am using the code below. However, I get an error while running the code.

I tried debugging and it seems that there might be some issue while computing the rank of the tensor. However, `sess.run(tf.rank(a))` successfully returns 3.   So I suppose there is some other issue with the tensor itself.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.array([[[1,  0,  0], [1,  1,  0]], [[0,  0,  0], [0, 1, 1]]])
hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(a, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)

sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hidden_layer))
```

The above code throws the error **AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndims'**, but I expect that a fully connected layer with weights and biases should be created.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, it would be really helpful if someone can maybe show a Python/NumPy equivalent of this implementation (without using tensorflow's dense), so that it's intuitive to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with the code: The `Dense` layer expects a `Tensor` as input instead of a Numpy array and the weights of the hidden layer need to be explicitly initialized. Here is the corrected code with some comments:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Make sure Dense layer is always initialized with the same values.
tf.set_random_seed(0)

# Dense layer will need float input
a = np.array([[[1,  0,  0], [1,  1,  0]], [[0,  0,  0], [0, 1, 1]]], 
        dtype=np.float32)
# Convert numpy array to Tensor
t = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)

# Create hidden layer with the array as input and random initializer that
# draws from a uniform distribution.
hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(t, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)

sess = tf.Session()
# Initialize Dense layer with the random initializer
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
# Print result of running the array through the Dense layer
print(sess.run(hidden_layer))
```

Btw as long as you're experimenting, you might benefit from using TensorFlow in [eager mode](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager) or using [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/) which has a friendlier interface.

Comment: Running this code gives TypeError: glorot_normal_initializer() got an unexpected keyword argument 'partition_info'. Is there a specific version of tensorflow to use?

Comment: I've tested it with TF 1.12

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. To give you some context, there is a larger code base that I am trying to understand and there, tf.layers.dense is used without explicitly specifying the kernel_initializer parameter and it is still working. Why is that?

Comment: I get the error with TF 1.11. Anyways, I removed the kernel_initializer in your example and it works!

Comment: Specifying the kernel_initializer parameter is not necessary, it will default to a random uniform initialization if you don't do that, I just added to make it explicit that there is initialization going on. (The truncated normal initialization is used more commonly than the uniform.)

Comment: I've removed the kernel_initializer param from the answer

Comment: Thanks. However, I still do not entirely understand what tf.layers.dense does to the input.. Would it be maybe possible to show a python/numpy equivalent of this implementation (without using tensorflow's dense), so its intuitive?

Comment: A dense layer is also commonly called a fully connected layer (if the type of the network is not explicitly specified, it usually only contains fully connected layers). A fully connected layer computes the dot product of its weights with the input and adds a bias term to it and then applies an activation function on top. Please post a new question if you need more help, as its beyond the scope of this question. (Good overview here: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should reshape a. Then input the a to hidden layer. And you should initialize the parameter.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
a = np.array([[[1,  0,  0], [1,  1,  0]], [[0,  0,  0], [0, 1, 1]]], dtype=np.int32)
a = tf.reshape(a, [-1, 4*3])
hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(a, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(hidden_layer))
```